# What is a "write to read-only page" fault called?

Tags: c, linux, x86, virtual-memory

OK, when a program tries to access a page which is not there in the physical memory, we say a page fault has occurred. But say, program tries to write to a page which is read-only and is there in the physical memory. What is that fault called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Intel terminology, it's `memory access violation`, aka `#AV` exception.

(I know, there is [linux] tag, but also there is [x86] tag.)

Answer (score 3):

This will usually raise a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (SIGSEGV).

Comment: Yes it should be segmentation fault for sure.

Answer (score 3):

**segmentation fault**

But in the circumstance of COW(copy on write), it is just **an exception which is to be handled by the kernel**.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write for details.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the architecture, but `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` are common signals sent when a process violates the permissions on its memory mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In some architectures, it will be a **SEGMENTATION FAULT**.

Comment: I think that "segmentation fault" is an operating system terminology, not a processor or instruction set architecture terminology. (See Abyx's answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's called segmentation fault, in linux SIGSEGV, or signal 11.